# Max and Index functions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I recently started using Excel heavily with my new job.

I have come to a new task where I am reducing large quantities of data down to more manageable sizes to be charted. My issue is I need to keep the MAX values of the data I am reducing.

Something along the lines of `=MAX(A1:A20)` where this will repeat every 20 intervals. So, `A1:A20`, `A21:A40`, `A41:A60` ... and so on.

Excel won't repeat this at the desired interval using the series extender.

The concept is very similar to this formula: ˙`=INDEX($D$3:$D$20403,(ROW(D3)-3)*20+1,1)` but with MAX value instead.

Comment: This can be done programmatically via a macro. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just by modifying the formula that you provide, I can arrive at:  =MAX(INDEX($D$3:$D$20403,(ROW(D3)-3)*20+1,1):INDEX($D$3:$D$20403,(ROW(D4)-3)*20,1)) which works just fine on test data.

Comment: you may try to use a pivot table. Create a new column like `=INT(ROW()/20)`, then group your data in the pivot by that one and add your value column as values summarized by `MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally posted this as a comment, but I'm moving it to an answer so I can look this up later :). It's harder to find comments in my personal history...

Just by modifying the formula that you provide, I arrive at:

```
=MAX(INDEX($D$3:$D$20403,(ROW(D3)-3)*20+1,1):INDEX($D$3:$D$20403,(ROW(D4)-3)*20,1))
```

Turning this into A1:A20, A21:A40 etc. is straightforward as well, just need to adjust the indices.

```
=MAX(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW(A1)-1)*20+1,1):INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW(A2)-1)*20,1))
```

Edit: Here's a picture of the second one in action. I did some spacing in the formula bar to show that it is two different items back to back.

[image]

Here's what happens when you look into the "Evaluate Formula" line on the second one (returning 40). You can see that it returns the desired behavior. [image]

Comment: Appreciate your input, unfortunately its not working for me.

Comment: @Workinatwork I'll edit with a screenshot to show how it works. Make sure you get the colon in there - it's 2 separate arguments.

Comment: Good example of how INDEX function can also return a cell reference rather than the value at that row/column index.

Comment: @Workinatwork Got pulled away from my desk for a sec. Put up 2 screenshots that demonstrate it is returning the desired behavior.

Comment: @Workinatwork no problem - glad it worked out for you. Have a good one!